# keras embedding options, batch_size and num of units -- value error about target shape

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I am writing my first keras model. I need to implement word embeddings. Here's my error:

```
        ValueError: Error when checking target: expected embedding_1 to have shape (55, 50) but got array with shape (55, 16)
```

below is some code. omitted is the code that assembles the x and y np arrays. Essentially what I'm doing is converting each word to it's token and stringing the tokens together. Then I pad each sequence out to 55 total. I would like to just feed this to the model, but I'm getting this error.

```
        batch_size=16
        words = 20000
        units = 50
        tokens_per_sentence= 55

        print (x.shape)

        x_shape =  x.shape

        model = Sequential()

        model.add(Embedding(words, units,input_length=tokens_per_sentence, batch_size=batch_size , input_shape=x_shape[1:]))

        model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

        model.train_on_batch(x, y)
```

I sort of expected units to be the size of the embedded vector. I would like to set it to somehting like 300 in my final model. I have a little experience with word2vec and gensim. There you just set the embedding vector size.

edit: I'm using keras 2.1.4 and the tensorflow 1.4.1 backend.

Comment: I think the problem should be about shape of `y` that you are feeding to the model, could you also print the shapes of `x` and `y`?

Comment: both x and y are (6,55,16). my goal is to have code that resembles an nmt model. I thought the x and y were both supposed to contain tokenized sentences. Of course that goal is for later. For now I was just looking at the Embedding layer.

Comment: One of the things I need to know is how or why keras expects one of the dimensions to be 50. I don't get that. My data doesn't have a 50 in it, and I thought it shouldn't. 50 is the embedding dimension. what does my input have to look like? how do I get that 50 in the input? Embeddings work much differently in keras than gensim?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedding layer in keras accepts a list of integers where each `int` number represent a word. (for example it is it's index in a dictionary) and in the output it embeds each word (`int` number) as a vector of shape `embedding_dim` (You've called it `units` in your code) so as stated in the [docs](https://keras.io/layers/embeddings/):

> input shape:  2D tensor with shape: (batch_size, sequence_length).
>
> Output shape: 3D tensor with shape: (batch_size, sequence_length, output_dim).

So in your code `x` should be of shape `(16, 55)` (and all of its element are < words = 20000). And `y` would be of shape `(16, 55, 50)`. In other words you feed 16 sentences that are 55 word long each and `Embedding` layer converts each word to a `50d` vector so now each of your 16 sentences is represented by 55 vectors of length 50.

Comment: it took me a while, but I may have it working without error.